# How can I download and save an image twice?

Tags: c#, .net, image, file, download

This is my code (taken from stackoverflow) for download, check and store an image on a fixed path:

```
private static void DownloadRemoteImageFile(string uri, string path)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    if ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ||
        response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved ||
        response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect) &&
        response.ContentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        using (Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(path))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            } while (bytesRead != 0);
        }
    }
}
```

now, let say I'd to create the image on both `path` and `path + "\duplicates\";` : what the best way to do it?

Recall the function with different path (so I need to download twice) or can I use multiple `outputStream`?

Comment: You can simply use multiple outputStreams

Comment: Is your goal to download it twice as a double-check of the data, or are you comfortable with downloading it only once and then duplicating it locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy file after your loop like this:

```
  if (File.Exists(path))
    File.Copy(path, duplicatePath);
```

Answer (score 5):

System.Io.File.Copy(path, duplicatePath)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use multiple outputStreams like this:

```
using (Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(path))
using (Stream outputStream2 = File.OpenWrite(duplicatePath))
{
   byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
   int bytesRead;
   do
   {
        bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        outputStream2.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    } while (bytesRead != 0);
}
```